# Permission does not show in admin page

Tags: python, django

I have added an app to my existing django site and to view it, I created an extra permission `overview.view`. But, I do not see it in my admin page, so I can also not assign this permission to any user. I think I have all files setup correctly, but I guess I am missing something. I have all the same files in the `overview` folder as I have in other working folders.

I do see the page, but somehow I am not logged in either.

This is my `urls.py`:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index')    
]
```

`models.py`:

from django.db import models

```
class Overview(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ('view', "May view the overview"),
        )
```

and (part of) `settings.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'overview.apps.OverviewConfig'
]
```

Comment: Did you run `makemigrations` and `migrate`?

Comment: I did now. Funny thing is that there are no changes, but the permissions do show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permissions are stored in the database and so when you add or remove them via the `Meta` for the model the same is not of course automatically reflected in the database. Permissions are added post the migrations via a `post_migrate` signal connected from the `auth` apps appconfig's `ready` method. See the [source code [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/d9cee3f5f2f90938d2c2c0230be40c7d50aef53d/django/contrib/auth/apps.py#L19-L22):

> ```
> post_migrate.connect(
>     create_permissions,
>     dispatch_uid="django.contrib.auth.management.create_permissions"
> )
> ```

Hence when one makes changes to the permissions one needs to run `makemigrations` and `migrate` to make sure they are added to the database.